# Import blank cells as NULL in CSV

Tags: ssis

I want import an SQL Table and I want the empty cells as NULLs using SSIS. So I want the csv file to contain Nulls instead of blank cells.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To convert source blanks into table NULLs:

1. In the *Flat File Source Editor* enable **Retain null values from the source as null values in the data source**
2. In the *OLE DB Destination Editor* enable **Keep nulls**

Answer (score 3):

In your data set all you need to do is add a derived column and set the value to this.

`YourColumn == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : YourColumn`

You may also be able to check the box on the source that says keep null values to solve the issue.
[image: RetainNulls]

Comment: Hi Zane. Thanks for your suggestion but I am importing a SQL table to a CSV file. Thanks

Comment: Then use the derived column.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whilst in the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, select the 'Edit Mappings' button

[image]

2. Once you can see your column mappings, click on the destination for the column you want to remain as NULL and select **ignore**

[image]

Comment: Won't this make everything null, though, for that column? I think they just want the rows that happen to be blank/empty in the csv file to be null.